# Need htaccess redirect code solution for subdomain URL to redirect to URL without www

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a domain example.com and I have added the following redirect code in .htaccess file to redirect to https://www.example.com/, https://test.example.com/ and https://www.example.com/test/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

1) When I load the URL in the browser example.com, it is redirected to https://www.example.com

2) I have created a subdomain folder ‘test’ in example.com. So when I load the URL example.com/test, it is redirected to https://www.example.com/test/

**Need solution for the following**:

1) When I load the URL test.example.com, it is redirected to https://www.test.example.com but I want it to be redirected to https://test.example.com

2) When I load the URL www.example.com/test, it is redirected to https://www.www.example.com/test/ but I want it to be redirected to https://www.example.com/test/

3) When I load the URL www.example.com, it is redirected to https://www.www.example.com/ but I want it to be redirected to https://www.example.com/

Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance

Comment: You'll need to provide some more details on your requirements. What does currently happen if you try to load `www.example.com`?

Comment: I have updated the question now

Comment: Sorry, now I have updated the question clearly

Comment: It redirects to https:// www.www.example.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect subdomain to https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}#%{HTTP_HOST} ^off#(sub\.domain\.com)$
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
#redirect main domain to https www
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}#%{HTTP_HOST} ^off#(?:www\.)?(example\.com)$
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

Clear your browser cache before testing these new redirects.

If you have multiple subdomains , you can use the following pattern to redirect them to https :

```
^off#(sub\.domain\.com|sub2.example.com|sub3.example.com|other)$
```